# How to show notification in component which is not mounted yet in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two component (Chat.js Phone.js) and a container (Full.js)
I am using following versions: react 16.1.1, react-router-dom:4.2.2. 
Following are my files:

Full.js

```
 class Full extends React.Component {
   render () {
   return(<Switch>
     <Route path="/phone" name="Phone" component={Phone} />
     <Route path="/chat" name="Chat" component={Chat} />
     </Switch>)
   }
 }
```

Chat.js

```
 class Chat extends React.Component {
   render () {
   return(<div>
     <div>Some chat code...</div>
   </div>);
   }
 }
```

Phone.js

```
 class Phone extends React.Component {

   state = {incomingCall : false}

   componentDidMount() {
     this.socket.on('incomingCall', () => {
     //Incoming call code
     //state changes and triggers notification div
     this.setState({incomingCall : true});
     });
    }

    render () {
      return(<div>
       <div>Notification div (Displays when incomingCall === true)</div>
      </div>);
     }
   }
```

Phone component receives incoming call via socket io and updates state and then shows notification div. My problem is when i am on Chat page, then i am unable to know incoming new call because in am not on Phone page.

I tried placing socket io code (Incoming call code) on Full.js (Container) , it shows notification but then when i go to Phone page, Phone component (which also has incoming call socket io code) did not show incoming call notification because component is mounted and all states have initial values (incomingCall will be false initially).

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: notifications are usually global. put your socket subscriber in some parent level component and send the state down

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem.
Here is one suggestions
Decouple the reading of the socket from the two components(Phone,Chat).
Create a class that takes care of reading the socket data and store the data in an
array.Both classes Chat and phone will read from The socketReader class.I will make the socket reader class a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I would place `socket` in `Full` component with the state `incomingCall: false`. Pass the state via props to `Phone and Chat` components. Then I would separate the Notification into its own component and place it inside `Phone and Chat` components and show when `incomingCall` is `true`.